# Coming Into Agreement With Thoughts

Tags: nedarim-shevuot, thought

If one comes in agreement with something mentally in regards to doing or not doing something are they making a vow?

Answer (score 3):

Other than צדקה nedarim are not valid when made in thought only.
Regarding Tzedaka it is a machlokes see shulchan aruch, choshen mishpat 212:8 and Rema, yoreh deah 358:13 . Per the mishna Berurah the Mechaber is also machmir (see mishna berura 694:6)

Also see -

- harav dov lior [response](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/17222)
- hidabroot Regarding tzedaka in [thought](https://www.hidabroot.org/article/237480#myfancy)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is a halachic concept called “devarim shebalev ainam devarim”-roughly “deutoronomies of the heart are not deutoronomies”, meaning that all vows must be verbalised as a general rule.

Comment: That's a hilarious translation

Comment: Thank you, I debated whether or not to do it, but decided to go for it.